# Map value from table using JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which I would like to query:

```
create table active_pairs
(
    pair                  text,
    exchange_id           integer
);


create table exchanges
(                        
    exchange_id         integer,
    exchange_full_name  text
);

INSERT INTO active_pairs (pair, exchange_id)

VALUES ('London/Berlin', 2),
       ('London/Berlin', 3),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 4),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 3),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 2),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 6),
       ('Huston/Berlin', 2);
       
INSERT INTO exchanges (exchange_id)

VALUES (2, 'Exchange 1'),
       (3, 'Exchange 2'),
       (4, 'Exchange 3'),
       (3, 'Exchange 21'),
       (2, 'Exchange 12'),
       (6, 'Exchange 11'),
       (2, 'Exchange 31');
```

I use this query to list all distinct pairs:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM common.active_pairs cp 
   GROUP BY pair, cp.exchange_id
HAVING COUNT(pair) = 1 
ORDER BY :sort
```

I need also to list the `exchange_full_name` mapped with the value `exchange_id`
Can you advise me how I can fix this using JOIN?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Your sample data has inconsistencies.  You may want to add a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain a little more what do you need?
If you need just a JOIN between the result of your query and exchanges you can use a subquery like this:

```
WITH pairs AS(SELECT *
   FROM active_pairs cp
   GROUP BY pair, cp.exchange_id
HAVING COUNT(pair) = 1)
SELECT p.pair, p.exchange_id, e.exchange_full_name
FROM pairs p
INNER JOIN exchanges e ON(p.exchange_id = e.exchange_id);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a37559ff8b6c0923b5a858298a85902c)

Comment: I just need to translate `exchange_id` to `exchange_full_name`(into result I need exchange name not a number)